# Not calculating "infinite" decimal places as program should with "math/big"

Tags: go, math

I am trying to write an application which can run an arbitrary number of decimal places of PI with the chudnovsky algorithm. I have 2 Problems though.

**Problem:**

1. There **should be an arbitrary number of decimal places**. In my case there are only 77 (if my count was correct)
2. The **result is not exactly PI**. Only the first 15 decimal places are exactly correct. There could be a correlation to the first problem though.

**Environment:**

I am coding in VSCode, running Fedora33 etc. In this case though I am 99.9% sure it's just an implementation fault.

**My approaches:**

1. I tried to figure out where the output of `.Acc()` is not "Exact" anymore. I figured out this occured at the line `sum = sum.Add(sum, sumElement(big.NewFloat(float64(i))))`. The return value of `.Acc()` from sumElement is `Exact` though. But hence the formula multiplies with `(-1)^k` each execution of the sumElement which leads to alternation. That is why I am not sure if `.Acc()` is a valid indicator in this case.
2. Probably somewhere in the code a finite Datatype is used in the wrong place so the further decimal places are being cut off.

**Code:**

The code should be executable and returning:

Exact

3.14159265358979319192147977918646609202090703009518871119759542708150903010657

Above

The first and last line are return values of the .Acc() function of the math/big package and the number in the middle is my current result for PI.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    result := big.NewFloat(0)
    sum := big.NewFloat(0)
    fmt.Println(sum.Acc())

    k := 12
    for i := 0; i <= k; i++ {
        sum = sum.Add(sum, sumElement(big.NewFloat(float64(i))))
    }
    result = Div(big.NewFloat(4270934400), Mul(Root(big.NewFloat(10005), 2), sum))
    fmt.Println(result)
    fmt.Println(result.Acc())
}

func sumElement(i *big.Float) *big.Float {
    iAsUint64, _ := i.Uint64()
    mulAsUint64, _ := Mul(big.NewFloat(3), i).Uint64()
    return Mul(
        Pow(
            big.NewFloat(-1),
            iAsUint64),
        Mul(
            Div(
                Factorial(
                    Mul(big.NewFloat(6), i)),
                Mul(
                    Pow(Factorial(i), 3),
                    Factorial(Mul(big.NewFloat(3), i)),
                ),
            ),
            Div(
                Add(
                    big.NewFloat(13591409),
                    Mul(big.NewFloat(545140134), i)),
                Pow(big.NewFloat(640320), mulAsUint64),
            ),
        ),
    )
}

func Pow(a *big.Float, e uint64) *big.Float {
    result := Zero().Copy(a)
    if e == 0 {
        return big.NewFloat(1)
    }
    for i := uint64(0); i < e-1; i++ {
        result = Mul(result, a)
    }
    return result
}

func Root(a *big.Float, n uint64) *big.Float {
    limit := Pow(New(2), 256)
    n1 := n - 1
    n1f, rn := New(float64(n1)), Div(New(1.0), New(float64(n)))
    x, x0 := New(1.0), Zero()
    _ = x0
    for {
        potx, t2 := Div(New(1.0), x), a
        for b := n1; b > 0; b >>= 1 {
            if b&1 == 1 {
                t2 = Mul(t2, potx)
            }
            potx = Mul(potx, potx)
        }
        x0, x = x, Mul(rn, Add(Mul(n1f, x), t2))
        if Lesser(Mul(Abs(Sub(x, x0)), limit), x) {
            break
        }
    }
    return x
}

func Abs(a *big.Float) *big.Float {
    return Zero().Abs(a)
}

func New(f float64) *big.Float {
    r := big.NewFloat(f)
    r.SetPrec(256)
    return r
}

func Div(a, b *big.Float) *big.Float {
    return Zero().Quo(a, b)
}

func Zero() *big.Float {
    r := big.NewFloat(0.0)
    r.SetPrec(256)
    return r
}

func Mul(a, b *big.Float) *big.Float {
    return Zero().Mul(a, b)
}

func Add(a, b *big.Float) *big.Float {
    return Zero().Add(a, b)
}

func Sub(a, b *big.Float) *big.Float {
    return Zero().Sub(a, b)
}

func Lesser(x, y *big.Float) bool {
    return x.Cmp(y) == -1
}

func Factorial(n *big.Float) *big.Float {

    if Lesser(n, big.NewFloat(2)) {
        return big.NewFloat(1)
    }

    return Mul(n, Factorial(Sub(n, big.NewFloat(1))))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `big.Float` has a specific, finite precision. The amount of precision depends on how the value is initially set. From the [`big.NewFloat` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#NewFloat)

> NewFloat allocates and returns a new Float set to x, with precision 53 ...

Since all your float values are created from `big.NewFloat`, you never have more precision than the `float64` literals you start with. An easy proof of concept is to add `.SetPrec(512)` to all your `NewFloat` calls, which will result in the accuracy you're looking for.